# Replace Umlauts in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, diacritics

i call a method before i save data and want to replace umlauts in a string like so:

```
def replace_chars
self.slug = self.slug.gsub(/[äöüß]/) do |match|
  case match
    when "ä" 'ae'
    when "ö" 'oe'
    when "ü" 'ue'
    when "ß" 'ss'
  end
end
end
```

my problem is, that i want to save the new string into the slug.
how can i do this?

Thanks a lot,

Peter

Comment: I dont know why, but now it works with my code.

Answer (score 3):

You can save a little bit of code by using gsub!. I also added the then's to make it (I believe) 1.9 compliant.

```
def replace_chars 
  self.slug.gsub!(/[äöüß]/) do |match|
    case match
    when "ä" then 'ae'
    when "ö" then 'oe'
    when "ü" then 'ue'
    when "ß" then 'ss'
    end
  end
end
```